# Do meteorites really land on Earth, or did the interviewee mean that ironically?

Tags: connotation

Technically speaking, landing is coming to rest after making contact with the ground.

Yes, but isn't it supposed to be smooth rather than violent?

Ships land, as do planes, drones, and skydivers.

Meteorites crash, fall ... uh ... collide with ... but *land*?

> Mazurek said the meteorite came with a barn he bought in 1988 in
>   Edmore. He said the farmer who sold him the property told him it
>   **landed** in his backyard in the 1930s.

Did he mean that ironically? "Meteorite landed": a quick google search returns 30,000 results.

I mean, come on. John Harrington comes to mind:

> Treason doth never prosper, what’s the reason?
>   For if it prosper,
>   none dare call it Treason.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84347/discussion-on-question-by-ricky-do-meteorites-really-land-on-earth-or-did-the-i).

Answer (score 34):

The verb **land** is a verbification of the noun **[land](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/land)**. So there is not really any "smoothness" inherent to the word. Sure, a meteor*ite* crashes, collides, impacts, destroys, ploughs into, wrecks *land*, but in every case, the space rock **makes contact** with the land. It "lands."

On a side note, a plane can land violently, but a meteorite simply 'lands,' unless you personify its action with, say, the wraths of the gods. :)

Comment: Oh, so now you're nounifying "verbify"? ;)

Comment: @NonnyMoose  If a noun is verbifirous, then it may be verbified.

Comment: Verbimus blurbimus! :)

Comment: @NonnyMoose Yes, they verbificationized it or, if you prefer, they performed an act of verbificationization. Note that this action is never referred to as verbificationizationing, since that would be ridiculous.

Comment: I may also add the usage of the verb when talking about "landing a hit" (be it with a punch, cannon, or anything else) to show how it can be used to describe a more violent form of contact.

Comment: Thus the old pilots saying "Any landing you can walk away from is a good one."  That is, not all landings are non-violent.

Comment: Sorry to say but I disagree with the answer - as I think context is important for the smoothness.   A landing on an object that is designed to hit land in a specific way, would suggest that it succeeded in doing so.  Failure to land in this specific way is a "crash land".  An object that has no design on how it is meant to hit land, can not crash land because it wasn't designed.

Comment: @UKMonkey: If some kind of object would typically *verb* in a particular fashion, saying the object *verbs* without being more specific would generally imply that it did so in its typical fashion.  I don't think the verb "land" is unusual in this respect.

Comment: @supercat well put. Supercat's razor?

Comment: @RBarryYoung a great landing is one where you can re-use the plane.

Comment: It's not the verbing that weirds the language; it's the renounification.

Comment: Another examples of using 'land' which do not have the same meaning as landing an aircraft.  Hurricanes are said to "land" in certain places.  In this case 'land' merely means to touch land and doesn't imply anything gentle or safe.

Comment: @NonnyMoose: [I don't mean to go all language nerd on you...](https://xkcd.com/1443/)

Answer (score 9):

A [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meteorites%20landed%2Cmeteorites%20hit%2C%20meteorites%20crashed&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeteorites%20landed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeteorites%20hit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmeteorites%20crashed%3B%2Cc0)   search shows “hit” as a more common verb used in relation to meteorites reaching the Earth.

[Land](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22meteorites%20landed%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) is also used, probably  on the following connotation:

> to hit or strike the ground, as from a height:
>
> - The ball landed at the far side of the court.

(Dictionary.com)

From [Perspectives on Astronomy](https://books.google.it/books?id=CXom04KGIL8C&pg=PA255&dq=%22meteorites%20hit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVuJDMufzdAhVD1xoKHRVnAg4Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22meteorites%20hit%22&f=false) :

> Meteorites hit Earth every day, and occasionally a large one can form a crater.

Answer (score 7):

I have been told by pilots on more than one occasion that

- Landing [an aircraft] is a controlled crash
- Any landing you walk away from is a good one

So all landings are crashes, with varying levels of violence, and your distinction is arbitrary and in particular not shared by the people to whom it applies.

If you want to argue that this is not the idiom then I point out that you opened the debate with a demonstration that sometimes it *is* the idiom.

Comment: "Any landing you walk away from is a good one" - a great landing is one where you can use the airplane again!

Comment: "Take off is optional. Landing is mandatory."

Answer (score 2):

The expression "Landing a blow" comes to mind.

It seems to indicate that landing is not necessarily a gentle one.

(As for "hit" - it does indeed seem better for a meteorite. But it has a slightly different meaning. The quote you supplied wanted to make the point that the meteorite *was there*.)

Comment: Good answer. ....

Comment: @Ricky Thanks. [....](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467425/leave-immediately-sooner-if-possible/467428#comment1128480_467428)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase [**make landfall**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20landfall) means

> to reach land after a journey by sea or air

and this describes exactly how a meteoroid arrives to become a meteorite. Indeed it describes the arrival of a space rock far better than the arrival of a ship, which does not fall to land, or a plane, which must not fall to land.

> The meteorite made landfall

Otherwise it could be a [**falling star**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_star) or a [**shooting star**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_Star) if its attempt to immigrate with a new name fails.

Comment: I thought it was pretty humorous.

Comment: Plus one, of course.

Comment: Thank you although its prime intention was to provide a relevant word.

Comment: So what. Verdi composed "Rigoletto" to please his mistress.

Answer (score 2):

***[Land](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/land)*** = arrive suddenly.

One fine morning in the 30s, out of nowhere, before you could say "meteorite," there it was!

> **2.4** *informal* (of something undesirable or unexpected) arrive suddenly.

Comment: My impression is that sense 2.4 is a metaphor derived from the tendency of various objects--such as meteorites--to land in sense 2.3, and to do so suddenly and unexpectedly. In short, I would have picked sense 2.3.

Comment: They certainly arrive suddenly. Anything big enough to reach the ground with a solid core will be travelling at terminal velocity which for an iron spear dropped from 30,000m is about Mach 3. Since meteors enter the atmosphere much higher and with significant velocity they often hit the ground at more than Mach 10. This is _not_ something you will see coming.

Answer (score 1):

The verb land comes with certain connotations that make it the preferred description in this case.

to land often refers to a body
a) ending its travels
b) touching down in the predictable or expected way

A is basic, boats land, planes land, thrown balls land. They come to a stop and they are done with their previous movement.
B is about something reaching rest as expected or intended. A plane landing implies that all is well. A sky diver landing implies a certain level of safety. Tricks on skateboard/snowboards are only considered to land if they hit the ground in the desired manner even though they will one way or another hit the ground.

Hope that isn't too long winded, but I thought the question was more about word choice and context then about definitions. English is full of words that mean the same thing but we pick the words that best imply what we mean.

Answer (score 1):

Crash and Land are both acceptable in this situation, Crash has overtones of violence and lack of control however.

Since a Metorite is unpiloted, they can be used pretty much interchangeably.

However, if a craft is airborne and piloted, Crash vs Land have very different connotations.

Remember that historically flight is only very recent, language takes a while to change, so there is no surprise that the terms are used interchangeably.

[Crash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crash#Verb) implies loud noises, possible destruction, violence, impact without intent, or unexpected impact.

[Land](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/land#Verb) implies an impact, possibly gently, possibly with intent, and likely comes from ships coming ashore, to earth or literal (noun) land, it's ships 'landing' that would have led to aircraft 'landing' being used to describe aircraft returning to earth gently. "Landing a punch" means that a punch correctly hit where you were aiming it.

If I were being descriptive:

"The meteorite landed in the backyard harmlessly."

"The meteorite crashed into my backyard destroying the shed."

Comment: A rock hitting your backyard at over 300 km/h (>200 mph) is unlikely to do so *harmlessly*. At the very best it's going to leave a sharp hole in your nice soft lawn.

Comment: In the scope of possible outcomes, leaving a crater in my lawn _is_ relatively harmlessly

Comment: Might even be useful for golf-putting practice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Small meteorites can 'land' because they reach terminal velocity in the lower atmosphere, so they're actual going as fast as a brick dropped from a plane. There's no strict rule about using 'land' as compared with 'crash' or 'impact'. If the meteorite hits the roof of a building and makes a hole then it will have 'crashed into a building', if it falls onto your lawn it will have 'landed' on your lawn.